# C# line selector?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, custom-controls

I have an application where the user needs to select a certain line to begin a parsing action.  My idea was to have a simple scrolling list where the user could select which line they wanted, when it was clicked the list would close and off the program goes.

I want to custom code the control though, to make it look as much like a normal textbox as possible, but highlight the line the user is currently selecting (and return the line number when it is clicked).

Of course I don't just want the code for this, it's something I need to learn to do; but are there any good resources that could help me create this new control?  Especially the vertical scroll bar that will be needed (the text can be hundreds of lines long).

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of creating your own custom control, why not just use a list box to store all the information that your potential use will want to select.  All the features you are looking for are already built into the control.  If I am missing something then please explain further.

Comment: Definitely an option, my goal is to "disguise" it as a textbox though, or just make it look like less of a listbox; maybe override the onpaint, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can (in theory) reuse any of the *TextBox controls by splitting on SelectionStart (caret position) which would get you the index of first CRLF (LastIndexOf in first substring) and select the whole line by setting selection length till next one (IndexOf in second substring). But as mentioned previously -- standard ListBox is way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a static textarea or is this based on some user input or copy/paste operation?  I ask because you can get into some potential issues with wrapping and you still have to deal with < IE8 not handling the SelectionStart correctly.

While not completely elegant, you could split the text based on line breaks and use a series of span/div tags for the content or (shudder) a table where you have the ability to grab the closest DOM elements with jQuery to get specific line offsets.  I don't think a textarea is going to be the best approach for what you are looking to do since it really isn't optimal for that sort of block level selection.